# How to separate the highlights panel fields layout from the popover fields layout in Lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience

I am setting up my popover views for all objects,

For example, for the Contact object - here is the popover in the Organization object:

[image]

And here is the highlight panel of the contact object:

[image]

The problem is that both field sets are defined from the primary compact layout that I select from the layout assignment page, but I need a different set for the highlight panel and a different one for the popover:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know if this could be done?

Another question is - does anyone know where do I define related lists for the popover - I can see them but cannot find a place to customize:

[image]

Thanks

Itai